# Why NodeJS fs.stat() not updating file.mtime when file has changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, ntfs

I have a simple scrirpt watching files stats like this:

I run fs.stat, let's say, every 2 seconds and looking for changes in result.
Other app can write to file any moment. Ans when it and when it happen I see size changed, but mtime stays the same.

ENV: **Windows10 / NodeJS v8.10.0**

- *I've tried fs.watch, but had the same/similar issue - no events on small changes.*
- *If I open log with sublime/notepad++ and add new lines manually and save - it works and date updates*

Script Example:

```
fs.stat(filename, (err, stat) => {
if (err) return console.log(err);
if (files[f]) {
    if (files[f].mtime !== stat.mtimeMs || files[f].size !== stat.size) {
        files[f].mtime = stat.mtimeMs;
        files[f].size = stat.size;
        files[f].changed = true;
    }
} else {
    let jnum = j_num(f);
    files[f] = {
        f: f,
        jnum: jnum,
        mtime: stat.mtimeMs,
        size: stat.size,
        proceed: 0,
        changed: true,
    };
}
console.log(files[f].f, files[f].size, files[f].mtime);
});
```

Output Example:

```
file                size  mtime

180428200919.01.log 23265 1524935545774.6038
180428200919.01.log 23265 1524935545774.6038
180428200919.01.log 23265 1524935545774.6038
180428200919.01.log 23348 1524935545774.6038
180428200919.01.log 23348 1524935545774.6038
180428200919.01.log 23348 1524935545774.6038
180428200919.01.log 23348 1524935545774.6038 << mtime the same
180428200919.01.log 23431 1524935545774.6038 << size changed
180428200919.01.log 23431 1524935545774.6038
180428200919.01.log 23431 1524935545774.6038
```

Can anyone explain this behavior and how to avoid it?
May it happens because writer-app didn't close (properly) log file?

Comment: not sure about fs.stat but I have had issues with `fs.watch` and `fs.watchFile` in node and hence I resorted to using https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar, this made my life a lot easier. You can do the same, and not even have to poll every 2 seconds. chokidar will notify you of changes as and when they happen.

Comment: @Yogesh_D Thanks, but it didn't help me. On nix system (and xos) it works perfect. But on windows I've got the same problem - no events on small changes for some reason. Actually because chokidar is simply (good) wrapper on fs.watch/watchFile, and I hah the same issue with fs.watch - no events.

Comment: oh thats bad as chokidar got me out of the same issues (nix vs windows). Anyways hoping someone gets you an answer.